# Converting a dataframe to text file in python

Tags: python, csv, text

I have data in csv file as:

| Name | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | sweet fruit |
| Orange | citrus fruit |
| Strawberry | citrus fruit |
| eggplant | vegetable |
| lemon | sour |

I want to convert it to a text file with separator between the 2 columns being :

```
Apple <EOL> sweet fruit
Orange <EOL> cirtus fruit
Strawberry <EOL> citrus fruit
eggplant <EOL> vegetable
lemon <EOL> sour
```

To do this I have written the code as:

```
df = open("../data.csv", "r")
df = '<EOL>'.join([i for i in df])  

df = df.replace(",", " ")  

print(df)
```

For this I get the output as:

```
Name Text
<EOL>Apple sweet fruit
<EOL>Orange cirtus fruit
<EOL>Strawberry citrus fruit
<EOL>eggplant vegetable
<EOL>lemon sour
```

I tried using skipinitialspace = True.. but that throws error. What can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`pandas.Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) for this task, consider following example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','B','C'],'y':['a','b','c']})
xy = df['x'].str.cat(df['y'],sep='---')
text = '\n'.join(xy)
print(text)
```

output:

```
A---a
B---b
C---c
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers Got this error for this

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem

```
# Import pandas package

import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
# making data frame

data = pd.read_csv('../Desktop/data.csv')

data.head()

print(data.columns)
    
# Get all names 
for col_name in data.columns:
   xy = data[col_name].str.cat(data[col_name],sep='<EOL>')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work since it adds an extra <EOL> at the end. Also it converts every row to a list with the square brackets which are not needed in the output.

Comment: I have updated the code please see if this works for you